# O que é o arquivo Boostrap.php e por que ele é usado ao invés do index.php?

Tags: php

Vejo que muitos frameworks/libraries possuem um arquivo `Index.php` que faz somente a inclusão do `Boostrap.php`, e nesse `Bootstrap.php` é incluído o autoload do composer e outros arquivos da aplicação, por que existe essa prática de usar o `Bootstrap.php` para iniciar a aplicação ao invés do `Index.php`?

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de onde viu isso?

Answer (score 0):

O index.php fica no diretório publico da sua aplicação src/public/index.php, e ele que inclui o bootstrap.php que onde é inicializado o seu código realmente e fica localizado no src/application/bootstrap.php, ou seja é por questões de segurança que somente o index.php fica no diretório publico da aplicação, assim independente do estado o servidor o arquivo não pode ser acessado, sendo que o arquivo pode conter informações sensiveis.

Leia [aqui](https://www.binpress.com/php-bootstrapping-crash-course/) um artigo explicando melhor.
[Essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313950/php-bootstrapping-basics) pergunta do stackoverflow também pode te ajudar.